# Why are smileys not displayed in webmail?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, safari, unicode, character-encoding

A friend of mine asked me why he cannot see smileys that people send him in a mail. He can see them in Mail on an iPhone, but on webmail on his MacBook, he sees codes like

```
\uD83D\uDE1E
```

that you can [search](http://www.charbase.com/1f61e-unicode-disappointed-face) on Google, and they indeed correspond to smileys.

I do not remember which site it was, but it was in
Google Chrome 55.0.2883.95 and Safari 9.1.3 (9537.86.7.8) on 
OS X 10.9.5.

Is this a particular setting that is wrong and does not display the smileys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:
  Simply because his webmail is not interpreting what it displays to him, so it shows it in raw form.  Your example looks like Unicode.

Not much he can do to control what others send, but if they send it in ASCII like this then all will be well:       ;-)    (That's a wink)

Check out this site.  It is a lot of fun, as its name implies:  http://www.emoticonfun.org/

My favorite one there is Sad and Confused, but I don't know how to type it.

˙ɥbnoɹɥʇ ʇǝb ʇou ʎɐɯ ɹo ʎɐɯ ʇxǝʇ uʍop ǝpısdn